# Three.js to visualize 3 slices of heatmaps in 3D space

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js to visualize a 3D matrix. For each 2D plane, I want the visualization to be a 2D heatmap, it will look like:

[image: Each plane can slide to show different slice of the matrix]

Users can drag each plane to show different slice of the matrix. The problem I'm having now is I can't find the best way in Three.js to visualize it. I drew each cell in the heatmap individually as a squre and color it. However, when the size of the matrix gets really huge, say 100000 * 500 * 200, it's very sluggish to draw.

I'm very new to 3D and Three.js. I looked into some examples and it seems to me that Three.js can actually visualize a huge amount of data by using particle system but I'm not sure how exactly I should utilize it. Some examples I found online didn't work for the latest version of Three.js.

Other requirements are to enable users to zoom, rotate and pan over the visualization.

A good example I found is http://www.georgeandjonathan.com/#1. At the end of the song, it has visualized a long sequence of data and you can rotate to see even the very beginning.

In short, my question is what techniques are available in three.js that I can use to visualize such plot, considering the size.

Thanks.

Comment: That sure is a lot of data... I suppose one way you could to this would be with a custom shader. Being new to 3D/Three.js, you've probably seen this term, and it's maybe not something you're quite ready to tackle. But the idea would be you pass in your data as a 3D matrix (just a 3D array), and the shader would apply colors to one of three planes, based on the fragment's position in space. This is the most memory efficient option I can think of right now.

Comment: @TheJim01Thanks! I'm looking at this example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles to see if I can figure out how the shader script works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I went over couple of examples, it looks like using `THREE.Points` constructed by a `BufferGeometry` and a `PointsMaterial` is sufficient to visualize the heatmaps.

```
var PARTICLE_SIZE = 15;
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size:PARTICLE_SIZE;
    , vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});

var rowNumber = 200, columnNumber = 10000;
var particleNumber = rowNumber * columnNumber;
var positions = new Float32Array(particleNumber * 3);
var colors = new Float32Array(particleNumber * 3);
for (i = 0; i < rowNumber; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < columnNumber; ++j) {
        var index = (i * columnNumber + j) * 3;

        // put vertices on the XY plane
        positions[index] = rowIndex * PARTICLE_SIZE;
        positions[index + 1] = columnIndex * PARTICLE_SIZE;
        positions[index + 2] = 0;

        // just use random color for now
        colors[index] = Math.random();
        colors[index + 1] = Math.random();
        colors[index + 2] = Math.random();
    }
}
// these attributes will be used to render the particles
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
var particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(particles);
```

[A good example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_points) that helped me.

There is one problem I haven't figured out yet, that is all the particles are facing towards the camera all the time. When the heatmap is rotated, these particles will always face you thus the whole plane is direction is changed. I will post my update when I find a solution.

Comment: "...all the particles are facing towards the camera all the time." Yes, they'll do that. Points have no volume--you can look at them as 1D objects in 3D space. The size of the square is simply to make the point visible. Now you _could_ use the particle system to help place Plane geometries, but then you're back to having millions of triangles bogging down your scene. Still, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you. :)

Comment: @TheJim01 Hi thanks for pointing that out. so since there is no way to change the direction. And you're saying if I try adding faces to the geometry to show 'real' colored squares thus it's possible to change the normals of each face, and then I'm back to the original problem? But can shader tackle this instead placing triangles?